# Distance law sound level

Tags: waves, acoustics

where are the limitations of the distance law? Can I calculate a sound from the free field back to the near field?

For example: If I have an impulse sound which is 80 dB loud at 2m. Is it than 118 dB in 0.025m (calculated)? If this calculation is not possible, how much decibel would it be instead approximately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound sources are generally very complicated, and generate both evanescent fields (which decay exponentially with distance) and propagating fields.  Far from the source the evanescent fields are completely negligible and the complicated diffraction patterns of the propagating field have simplified dramatically.  It is only in this "far field" that any distance law can be valid.

If you are trying to determine the sound level at a point closer to the source but still in the far field, then yes you can use the further data to inform the nearer.  However, if you are trying to reconstruct the near field (where the pressure field is complicated), no you cannot completely reconstruct it.  The best you can do is to reconstruct the propagating portion, which is a non-trivial inverse problem (e.g., look up acoustic hologrophy).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. The noise was calculated for measuring the noise from a normal slap on the face in combat sports (it was done on a dummy, not on a human). Are the 118 dB valid for this? If not, how much decibel are approximately not considered by this calculation (just an estimation).

Comment: I'm confused about where you got the 118 dB estimate from, so I don't know if it is reasonable or not.   The distance law I recall (still not valid here) is 3 dB down per doubling of distance, which would yield $80+3\log_2(2/0.025)\approx99dB$.  What distance law are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it is 6 dB/doubling of distance.  I know where you got your estimate from.

Comment: So, can you give me an estimation, if this is correct?

Comment: How much decibels are not considered by this calculation approximately?

Comment: It depends on how accurate you want to be.  If you are OK with a $\pm5$ dB uncertainty, then sure, go with 118 dB (you will probably be a little high in your estimate).  If you want to be really accurate, you need to know a lot more about the problem.

Comment: Yes I know, but what would you expect if I would make it really accurate? How much decibels would it be more at a rough guess?

Comment: I don't know.  I am not that familiar with slaps, and it would take a lot more effort than I am willing to put in right now to give you a reasonable estimate.  If I were to investigate, I would try to model the slap as a baffled impulse ring source.  There are some classic texts that address similar problems.

Comment: It might be easier to get a microphone and go and actually measure it.

Comment: Sorry Michael M., the stackexchange app didn't show me your +- 5 dB estimation. I switched to the internet site and then I saw it. Thank you for that. But what did you mean with "you will probably be a little high in your estimate"? I thought, that I would be to low in my estimate according to this: https://goo.gl/images/nNDokX

Comment: Can you please answer me, Michael M.

Comment: Two points.  (1) The far field is an average of the near field details, and so parts will be louder than the far field will suggest and parts will be quieter.  Thus, as mentioned in the post you sent, the levels will vary widely.  The graph you showed is just a schematic and should not be used for calculations.  Also, I pulled the $\pm5$ dB out of my head, trying to give you an idea of what is happening - I don't know what the uncertainty really is.

Comment: (2) The inverse square law (6 dB per doubling of distance) assumes a point source.  This is never truly the case.  The source is always part of a distribution that is averaged out.  If you were to take the inverse square law literally, then as you get closer to the source the level would go to infinity, which is not physical.  Thus, at some distance the inverse square law will provide an over-estimate of the level, which is why I made my previous comment.

Comment: One last thing about your last comment. Would there be rather an overestimation for 0.025m (using the distance law) or rather an underestimation because of the approximation in my certain case? What do you think.

Comment: I really can't say, as 2.5 cm is too small of a distance.  It would depend on where around the hand you are looking and what the dominant frequency is.  Furthermore, the evanescent fields make everything harder.  I am sorry, but I don't think the level you are looking for can be easily estimated.

Comment: But the distance law should give me a good approximation for now?

Comment: Sure.  Why not.  Just be sure you explain what you are doing and what sources of error may be.